# PHP code not saving in a Computed Field

Tags: 7, entities

I'm using Drupal 7 and the [Computed Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field) module.  I have this problem with both the *Custom Content Type* and *Custom Entity Type*.

When I add a computed field and go to the *Field Settings*, I type some *PHP code* and click the *Save field settings* button, the page merely reloads with my code deleted and I'm back where I started.

Is this a bug? Or is it maybe not liking my code and deleting it rather than causing a fatal error? But it fails even with simple code like `$entity_field[0]['value'] = "test"`; that gets deleted too. Is it possibly not allowing me to add a *computed field* since I have already created contents and entities of those contents and entity types?

Comment: its possible that there is a silent error condition in mysql (perhaps because the module is awaiting updates?) that is preventing the data from being saved. Have you checked your error logs after trying to save?

Comment: All the modules are up to date.  How do you check the error logs?

Comment: ok - assuming that both the modules and their corresponding database updates have been completed then the only place left to isolate this is in the error logs. You can look in the error logs in your drupal admin reports (admin/reports/dblog) assuming you have database logging enabled. Otherwise, you'll need to find where on your server your error logs are being output to and look for clues there.

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like Database logging is not enabled by default.  I went ahead and enabled that and will give this another try to see what it registers.

Comment: Well, that's strange.  It seems to save now.  Not sure why it didn't save before and does now.  Could be a module update as you suggested or maybe a database update that was performed with it.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: So strange.  Same problem again.  Just made a computed field and it went fine.  When I went to make a second one, it's not letting me save anything, whether the same code as the first or something simpler.  Checked the log and there is no error registered.

Comment: I did find some errors regarding the Schema module when I ran cron.  For several fields it was reporting "no Schema type for mysql type datetime."  After disabling Schema and running cron, these errors went away.  Tried putting in the Computed Field code and now it works.  I don't understand the Schema error, but seems to be fine now.